# Can't build game in Xcode 7.2

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, keychain

When i build my game from xcode to iphone5, have error:

> ld: library not found for -lSSKeychain clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ican't fix?

Comment: Seems like you missed downloading 3rd party libs. Follow the documentation of how to build the game.

Comment: you most probably missed to reference ISSKeychain in your `Library Search Paths` in xCode

Comment: i add full ioskeychain.mm sskeychainquery.mm sskeychain.h sskeychainquery.h but it still missed

Comment: library should be a .lib file, so probably it's missing somehow

Comment: _CallNative__SaveImage_m12799 in Bulk_CaptureAndSaveLib_0.o

     (maybe you meant: _CallNative__SaveImage_m12799)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


now i have only error :(

Comment: this last error means that there is a method that is missing. A library is trying to call _CallNative__SaveImage_m12799 but it's not defined anywhere in xCode project. most probably the 3rd party .m or .mm script which has that method did not get copied to xCode, or did not get referenced correctly.

Comment: Thank, i will try.